# Can't get a json response from my Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a Rails sever and I'm trying to make a fetch request from a React client. I want to get the comments of a post every time a new comment is made.

`posts_controller.rb`

```
  # GET /post/1
  # GET /post/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.kept.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.kept.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
```

My React component

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/posts/post-title')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Result

```
res Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/posts/post-title", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

I open that Response but I don't see any comments json. I have tried doing `res.json()` but I get `undefined`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change your show action to this

```rb
def show
  @post = Post.kept.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments.kept.order(created_at: :desc)
  render json: @comments
end
```

and your JS to this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/posts/post-title')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((post) => {
      console.log(post)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err", err);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: I also have to show html in the page. I tried something like this
`respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end`
But I get `err SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`